# Positioning subnodes above nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

[image]

I am trying to create a picture as above, but I have issues with positioning as can be seen below.

[image]

My code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{equation*} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node{$\subnode{m1}{$x$} \subnode{m2}{$\rightarrow$} \subnode{m3}{$y$}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[above= 3mm of m2](M1){$w$};
\node[below= 3mm of m3](M2){$\varepsilon$};
\draw [->] (M1) edge (m1);
\draw [->] (M1) edge (m3);
\draw [->] (M2) edge (m3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't understand why the w is not exactly above subnode m2 and \varepsilon is not below y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! There is no need for `\subnode` here, you can just put `\tikzmarknode`s in the equation. However, I would just do the full thing with `tikz-cd` anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark,cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} 
\tikzmarknode{m1}{x} \tikzmarknode{m2}{\rightarrow} \tikzmarknode{m3}{y}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[above= 3mm of m2](M1){$w$};
\node[below= 3mm of m3](M2){$\varepsilon$};
\draw [->] (M1) edge (m1);
\draw [->] (M1) edge (m3);
\draw [->] (M2) edge (m3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\bigskip
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0pt,row sep=1.2em]
 &w\arrow[dl]\arrow[dr]& \\
 X \arrow[rr]& & y \\
 & & \varepsilon\arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the question raised in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0pt,row sep=1.2em]
 &w\mathrlap{[\text{omitted value}]}\arrow[dl,"f"']\arrow[dr,"g"]& \\
 x \arrow[rr]& & y \\
 & & \varepsilon\arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! What if I want to add some explanation on w. E,g, w [extra variable], but still want the arrows under w?

Comment: @Mike This is what `tikz-cd` is basically made for. Try `w\arrow[dl,"f"']\arrow[dr,"g"]` instead of `w\arrow[dl]\arrow[dr]`.

Comment: That is pretty useful too, but what I wanted was a comment on the right of w. So instead of w,  w[ommited variable], but the bars to still start at w. I tried to put it on the next col, but it loses the symmetry. I can always put it above as well. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: @Mike I added something along those lines to the answer.